# OpenGL es 2.0 render issues on certain devices

Tags: android, xamarin.android, opengl-es-2.0, samsung-mobile, opentk

I'm experiencing a very bizarre issue with OpenGL ES 2.0 on certain android devices. I'm using OpenTK and Xamarin.Android

The following method renders the screen, it is capped at 1FPS for testing purposes:

```
int hexagonID = 15;
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        br.updateHex(hexagonID++, GameUtils.Green, true); 
        GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        spriteMapTexture.use();
        program.Uniforms["mvp"].SetData<Matrix4>(mvp);
        program.Uniforms["hextex"].SetData<int>(0);
        br.RenderBoard();
        SwapBuffers();
    }
```

RenderBoard method:

```
 //Render the board
    public void RenderBoard()
    {
        _program.Use();
        boardVAO.Bind();
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (uint* ptr = indices)
            {
                GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, new IntPtr(ptr));
            }
        }
        boardVAO.Unbind();
        _program.Unuse();
    }
```

Expected behavior is that a hexagon's color changes every second. This code **works** on a OnePlusOne phone running an Adreno 330 & ES 3.00

However, this code does **not work** on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running an Adreno 225 & ES 2.00. I don't understand why this would be the case as I do not call any 3.00 functions and my shaders are written for GLSL 1.00

ScreenShots: 
OnePlusOne, Expected Behavior after a few seconds
[image]

Galaxy S3, No change after a few seconds
[image]

libEGL trace:

```
08-08 20:54:36.026 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:36.977 D/libEGL  (18551): glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2); 
//update Board Buffer
08-08 20:54:36.977 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:36.987 D/libEGL  (18551): glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 17920, (const GLvoid *) 0x00000000, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
08-08 20:54:36.987 D/libEGL  (18551): glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 17920, (const GLvoid *) 0x67b15020);
08-08 20:54:36.987 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:36.997 D/libEGL  (18551): glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3);
08-08 20:54:36.997 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:36.997 D/libEGL  (18551): glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8960, (const GLvoid *) 0x00000000, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
08-08 20:54:36.997 D/libEGL  (18551): glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 8960, (const GLvoid *) 0x67b1a020);
08-08 20:54:36.997 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
//Clear and Blending
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glEnable(GL_BLEND);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
08-08 20:54:37.007 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551): glUseProgram(3);
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
//set uniforms
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551): const GLfloat value[] = {
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551):     0.00277778, 0, 0, 0,
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551):     0, -0.0015625, 0, 0,
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551):     0, 0, -1, 0,
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551):     -1, 1, 0, 1
08-08 20:54:37.017 D/libEGL  (18551): };
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_FALSE, value);
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glUniform1i(1, 0);
//draw elements
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glBindVertexArrayOES(1);
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2880, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid *) 0x67b12020);
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glUseProgram(0);
08-08 20:54:37.027 D/libEGL  (18551): glGetError();
```

any insight is greatly appriciated

UPDATE:

I found the following messages from logcat, not sure if they are relevant

```
08-08 20:54:31.321 W/Adreno-GSL(18551): <get_panel_settings:3802>: Android framework reported version 2. So, don't force ES30
```

and

```
08-08 20:54:31.521 W/Adreno-EGL(18551): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:603>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
```

UPDATE2: My indices are uints, could this be the issue?

UPDATE3: I have narrowed the issue down to devices running Android 4.4.2; I upgraded a 4.4.2 phone to 6.0 and this issue went away. Is there a bug in 4.4.2?

Comment: Yes, uint indices could be a problem. They are not a standard ES 2.0 feature, and can only be used if the `OES_element_index_uint` extension is supported on the device.

Comment: And of course VAOs are an extension as well.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I switched my indices to ushorts, however that didn't seem to have an effect. Doesn't the fact that the Samsung phone is rendering something mean both those extensions are supported?

Comment: @RetoKoradi looks like `OES_element_index_uint` and VAOs are supported by my particular device: http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/gles_generatereport.php?reportID=144

Comment: Could it be `GL_OES_EGL_sync` ?